# Could not get the Access token from GTMOAuth2Authentication object Google+ api for ios

Tags: api, ios7, google-plus, google-oauth

I'm trying to get the accessToken after being authenticated to get all profile informations.
I added a sign In button as shown in this tutorial https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in?hl=fr

However, after getting the auth object from the GPPSignIn delegate method `finishedWithAuth:error:` , I'm not able to get the access Token from it.

How should I proceed after getting the GTMOAuth2Authentication object?

Any hints will be appreciated.

thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You can get the accesstoken by invoking the following delegte method :

```
 -(void)finishedWithAuth: (GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
                   error: (NSError *) error {

   NSString *oauthToken = auth.accessToken

}
```

*Please add the following framework:
   1. `GooglePlus.framework`
   2. `GoogleOpenSource.framework`
And Import the follwing framework on the view controller :

```
# import GooglePlus/GooglePlus.h

# import GoogleOpenSource/GoogleOpenSource.h
```

If you want the source code, Please let me know.